# How to Descrypt Password in SQL Server 2012 using DES?

Tags: sql-server

I want to decrypt password in SQL Server 2012 using DES to send that password in the mail using a SQL Server job.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - just SQL Server **2012** - corrected

Comment: You should not be decrypting password, generate a new password. Maybe this is of your interest http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html

Comment: If you are saving passwords you have an insecure system that is vulnerable to attacks that can expose all the user names and passwords. Instead you need to save salted and hashed version of the passwords and use a password-reset method to handle forgotten passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be de-encrypting passwords. And either not send passwords thru the emails!

And no, there's usually a random salt in the encryption, so you cannot decrypt it like that. Only Brute Force, because it's weak encryption method nowadays.

For Brute Force you can use for example `pwdcompare` - More at [MSDN pwdcompare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx)